# I can't work out a to call my python function properly

Tags: python, function

When I try to call a function from another python code file, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "%filepath%", line 2, in module
>
> print(colour(red) + "Test")
>
> NameError: name 'red' is not defined

from this code:

```
from hcolours import *
print(colours(red) + "Test")
```

When I have it defined in my code:

```
def colours():    
    reset = '\033[0m'
    bold='\033[01m'
    disable='\033[02m'
    underline='\033[04m'
    reverse='\033[07m'
    strikethrough='\033[09m'
    invisible='\033[08m'
    black='\033[30m'
    red = '\033[31m'
```

and so on (the full code is [here](https://github.com/henos1029/stack_code/blob/master/hcolours.py))

I have tried lots of different ways to get it to work but I can't understand it,
I have even tried putting it up on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/)

Do you need to do something special?

I'm completely stuck

Comment: `red` != `'red'`... the variable `red` is undefined.

Comment: `red` is not a parameter for `def colours()`, and to import it use this: `import hcolours.colours`

Comment: @FishingCode, I get: No module named hcolours.colours, hcolours is not a package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you mix `function` and `class`...

From your code, you want to print with color, so you defined a function, but without argument. Maybe you want a class here?

```
class colours:    
    reset = '\033[0m'
    bold='\033[01m'
    disable='\033[02m'
    underline='\033[04m'
    reverse='\033[07m'
    strikethrough='\033[09m'
    invisible='\033[08m'
    black='\033[30m'
    red = '\033[31m'

print(colours.red + "Test" + colours.reset)
```

Then a possbile function could be

```
class colours:    
    reset = '\033[0m'
    bold='\033[01m'
    disable='\033[02m'
    underline='\033[04m'
    reverse='\033[07m'
    strikethrough='\033[09m'
    invisible='\033[08m'
    black='\033[30m'
    red = '\033[31m'

def print_colours(str):
        print(colours.red + str + colours.reset)
#we can test the string as below
#print_colours("Test")
```